# Same query, different execution plan with limit and sort by. Should I change the index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, query-performance

I have a table with 1,000,000 records. Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_serial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`category_id`,`item_serial`),
)
```

When I execute this query:

```
select * from `items`
where `category_id` = 1  
order by `id` asc 
limit 22649;
```

It takes about 0.5 seconds, which I find to be a lot.

If I execute the explain for the query I get the following result:

```
type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra
-----|----------------|----------------|---------|-------|-------|----------|-----------------------------------------
ref  | unique_index   | unique_index   | 4       | const | 498253| 100.00   | Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

If I execute the exact same query, but just remove 1 digit from the limit, so 22648 instead of 22649:

```
select * from `items`
where `category_id` = 1  
order by `id` asc 
limit 22648;
```

The query duration is much faster, about 0.003 seconds.

I get the following result for explain:

```
type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra
-----|----------------|----------------|---------|-------|-------|----------|-------------
ref  | unique_index   | PRIMARY        | 8       | null  |  45296| 50.00    | Using where
```

As you see the explain varies for both queries and the query duration is also very different.

I also played around with the unique_index and added the id column to that index, changing it to :

```
UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`id`, `category_id`, `item_serial`),
```

When I did this, I did not anymore get the different results, but always got the same explain result using the new index, and with a fast result of about 0.003 seconds.

So I have 2 questions:

1 - Why does the same query with a different limit produce different execution plans?

2 - Would you recommend adding the id column to the unique_index for better performance? I find it strange to add it because it makes no sense in terms of uniqueness, since the id is auto-incremental and never will repeat, but it does solve this problem of performance in this case.

Would appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: Using mysql version 5.7.30. Also would like to note that when the records increase, so instead of 1,000,000 I have 5,000,000, the performance gets worse when using the `unique_index` (`category_id`, `item_serial`), going up to above 1 second execution time, while when using the right limit which triggers PRIMARY index, query remains very fast.

Comment: Since id field is the PK, it is implicitly added to all indexes defined on that table - assuming you are using innodb table type.

Comment: @Shadow, thanks for your comment. I am finding it hard to understand the context of you comment related to my question. Could you expand a little on that? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the accepted answer below. It says the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found a case where the Optimizer is torn between

- Filter on `category` -- Covering index, but need to sort
- Read data in order -- Avoid sort by reading in `id` order, but have to check each row.

It just *happened* that the Optimizer's coin flip was at exactly 22649.  Tomorrow it may be different -- larger *or* smaller.

Change `1` (for `category_id`) to the largest value in the table; the timings may go really bad.

As already mentioned, an index *starting* with these two columns is optimal:

```
INDEX(category_id, id)
```

Note:  InnoDB tacks the `PRIMARY KEY` column(s) onto the end of each secondary index.  Effectively, the table is two BTrees:

```
(id, category_id, item_serial) -- All the data, in PK order
(category_id, item_serial, id) -- secondary index plus PK
```

Re 0.003 sec.  -- That smells like the Query cache was turned on.  It is deceptive.  Suggest re-timing with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`

Should you change the index?  Well,

```
UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`category_id`,`item_serial`)
```

is both an index and a uniqueness constraint.  You would lose the uniqueness constraint if you change this.  So, you are stuck with *adding*

```
INDEX(category_id, id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer!
I would like to add another filter to the query and ask for your advice if you dont mind. If I change the query to this:

`select * from items where category_id = 1 and id > 50000  order by id asc limit 22648;`

And I use the index you suggested INDEX(category_id, id), I still get the behavior where sometimes the added index is used INDEX(category_id, id), and sometimes the PRIMARY KEY is used.

What kind of index would you recommend for such a query? With the added `id >` condition.

Comment: @BernardWiesner - I would _expect_ that index to benefit that `SELECT`.  A possibly related question:  What percentage of the table has `category_id = 1`?  I _think_ that factors into the Optimizer's algorithm.

Comment: You could file a bug report:  bugs.mysql.com .  But they would want a test case.

Comment: Thanks! I will make some additional tests, and maybe file a bug report as well.